# Altcoin - genesis block - TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: altcoin, python, altcoin-development, genesis-block

I'm trying to use the genesis script from innova to generate a genesis block of Xevan_hash

https://github.com/innovacoin/GenesisH0/blob/master/genesis.py

I'm using these parameters:
python genesis.py -a xevan_hash -z "a news string" -p "myprivate key"

and I always get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "genesis.py", line 224, in <module>
    main()
  File "genesis.py", line 15, in main
    tx = create_transaction(input_script, output_script, options)
  File "genesis.py", line 74, in create_transaction
    Bytes("version", 4),
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command in your terminal:

pip install construct==2.5.2

Then try to run the python script again.